# Closing questions using a non-valid argument

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, asking-questions, close-reasons

I posted yesterday [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/353181/148451) and I was put **on hold as off-topic** because:

> "Bug reports and problems with the development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues."

The question was about moving the Gnome 3.10 close button on the left side. This is **NOT** a Gnome bug, and I was not reporting a bug there. I was asking just for a solution about that...

So, the question is: what happens if a moderator or 5 users with enough reputation put on hold my question, **but** their argument is **NOT** a valid one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if you want to adress a specific closure on meta, you should do that on the per-site meta and not here on MSO. Moderators are automatically notified about new meta posts, and you need either a moderators or five users with reopen privilege to do something about this problem. You have a much better chance of finding those on meta.askubuntu than here.

You could also just post a comment on your question and @notify the moderator that closed it, if you don't want to make a full meta post.

The closing mechanism has built-in mechanisms to correct mistakes, even moderator closures are reversible by the community.